# Python regular expression to get words enclosed in {}'

Tags: python, regex

How to get the all the words which are enclosed in between {} in a string?

For example:

```
my_string = "select * from abc where file_id = {some_id} and ghg='0000' and number={some_num} and date={some_dt}"
```

output should be like:

```
[some_id,some_num,some_dt]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re
my_string = "select * from abc where file_id = {some_id} and ghg='0000' and number={some_num} and date={some_dt}"

result = re.findall(r'{(.+?)}', my_string)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it's words you are after,

```
import re
ans = re.findall("{([A-z]+)}", my_string)
```

The pattern `[A-z]` includes all upper-case and lower-case characters. `[A-z]+` to capture at-least one or more characters, surrounded by `()` to capture the matches.

Output:

```
['some_id', 'some_num', 'some_dt']
```